# AgGrid: applyColumnState is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am using ag-grid in my project and I have problem with applying state of table. Here is my code fragment from `onGridReady` function:

```
 this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;

    if (!window.colState) {
        console.log("no columns state to restore by, you must save state first");
    } else {
        this.gridColumnApi.applyColumnState({
            state: window.colState,
            applyOrder: true,
        });
        console.log("column state restored");
    }
```

It is taken from ag-grid of course.
Right under it I have
`this.gridColumnApi.getAllColumns()`
and `this.gridColumnApi.autoSizeColumns()`
functions that works fine.

The problem is that `this.gridColumnApi.applyColumnState` gives me this error.

```
TypeError: _this.gridColumnApi.applyColumnState is not a function
```

I cannot understand why other functions called on `this.gridColumnApi` works but `applyColumnState` doesn't. Any suggestions?

@edit
I even tried this one:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    window.colState = this.props.gridColumnApi.getColumnState();
    console.log("column state saved");
    if (this.props.gridColumnApi.applyColumnState) {
        devLog("IT IS HERE");
    } else {
        devLog("its not");
    }
    this.gridColumnApi.resetColumnState();
    console.log("column state reset");
}
```

but I get `applyColumnState` and `resetColumnState` is not a function errors, what is wrong here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check your AgGrid version. `ColumnApi.applyColumnState()` was added in version [24.0.0](https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-changelog/?fixVersion=24.0.0).

Comment: yeah you are right, I had to update AgGrid to version 24.0.0, thank you so much! :) problem solved

Answer (score 6):

If you are stuck with a lower ag-grid version (< 24.0.0), then use `gridOptions.columnApi.setColumnState(prevState)`

With ag-grid version 24.0.0 and above you can use -

```
gridOptions.columnApi.applyColumnState({
         state:prevState,
         applyOrder: true,
       });
```

Comment: Just added for anyone who is using a lower version. I was facing the same issue, and was using version 23.2